Is -(으)ㄹ the only morpheme that always tensifies the following consonant?
I'm wondering if there's a list of morphemes that always tensify the following consonant (outside of the phenomenon of compound tensing), or if the irrealis adnominal suffix -(으)ㄹ is the only such morpheme with this behavior. I remember reading something about tensification after the numerals 여덟 and 열, but I can't find the source again and I don't think it was a particularly authoritative source.

Evidence for 여덟 being a regular form of post-obstruent tensification: 임석규 Im SK (2013) 경음화, 남은 몇 문제 Some issues remaining on tensification.
